# How i can change the order of the fields and the fields names inside my CSVHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, csvhelper

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 web application + entity framework 5.0, and i have the following method which call a function named `AdvanceSearchStoredProcedure`, where this function will call a stored procedure:-

```
     public IQueryable<AdvanceSearchSP_Result> AdvanceSearch(NetworkAdvanceSearch na)
      {

        var r = entities.AdvanceSearchStoredProcedure("network",na.AssetTypeID,
        na.ip, na.ipselection, na.mac, na.macselection);
        return r.AsQueryable();           

      }
```

then i am calling this method from my action method as follow:-

```
public ActionResult AdvanceSearchIndexExport(AdvanceSearchSP_Result2 ns)

        {
            var result = WriteCsvToMemory(repository.AdvanceSearch(ns.NetwotkAS).ToList());
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(result);
            return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "text/csv") { FileDownloadName = "export.csv" };
        }
public byte[] WriteCsvToMemory(IEnumerable<AdvanceSearchSP_Result> records)
      {
          using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
          using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
          using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
          {
              csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
              streamWriter.Flush();
              return memoryStream.ToArray();
          }
      }
```

here is a partial class for my `AdvanceSearchSP_Result` and its MetadataType class:-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AdvanceSearchSP_Result_Validation))]

    public partial class AdvanceSearchSP_Result
    {


    }
public class AdvanceSearchSP_Result_Validation{
        [Display(Name="Service Tag")]
        public string SERVICETAG { get; set; }
         [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
        public string SERIALNO { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Resource Tag")]
         public string Tag { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Resource Name")]
         public string RESOURCENAME { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "State")]
         public string StateName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Type")]
         public string TypeName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Site Name")]
         public string sitename { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
         public string cusotmername { get; set; }
         public bool ismanaged { get; set; }
}
```

now i am facing these problems inside the generated `.CSV` file:-

1. the fields title will be equal to the column names inside the database, and not as defined inside the `AdvanceSearchSP_Result_Validation` MetadataType class.
2. second question, i am not sure how i can change the order of the columns? as currently the order will be as the one defined inside the stored procedure..for example how i can force the `ismanaged` to be the first column inside the .csv file??

i am using the CSVHelper https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/ library to do the actual CSV export.

**EDIT**
now i added this class:-

```
public sealed class SPMap : ClassMap<AdvanceSearchSP_Result>
    {
        public SPMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Tag).Name("Resource Tag").Index(0);
        Map(m => m.RESOURCENAME).Name("Asset Name").Index(1);
        Map(m => m.cusotmername).Name("Customer Name").Index(2);
        Map(m => m.sitename).Name("Site Name").Index(3);
        Map(m => m.StateName).Name("Asset State").Index(4);
        Map(m => m.ismanaged).Name("ismanaged").Index(5);
        Map(m => m.TypeName).Name("Technology Type ").Index(6);
        Map(m => m.SERVICETAG).Name("Service Tag").Index(7);
        Map(m => m.SERIALNO).Name("Serial Number").Index(8);

    }
    }
```

then i modify my method to include the configuration as follow:-

```
 public byte[] WriteCsvToMemory(IEnumerable<AdvanceSearchSP_Result> records)
      {
          using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
          using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
          using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
          {
              csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
              csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SPMap>();
              streamWriter.Flush();
              return memoryStream.ToArray();
          }
      }
```

but still i got the old names & the old order.. so seems  the `public sealed class SPMap : ClassMap<AdvanceSearchSP_Result>` did not have any effect...

Comment: [I](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a map to specify the names and indices of the columns:

```
public sealed class SPMap : ClassMap<AdvanceSearchSP_Result>
{
    public SPMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SERVICETAG).Name("Service Tag").Index(0);
        Map(m => m.sitename).Name("Site Name").Index(1);
        /*repeat for other properties */
        ..
        .. 
    }
}
```

Then you need to register this:

```
csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SPMap>();
```

I believe that'll work.

See :
http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/mapping

Comment: but where i need to register this `csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SPMap>();` ?? inside the global.asax?

Comment: can you please advice when i need to register this `csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SPMap>();`?? inside my action method ?

Comment: i tried your appraoch.. but it did not work.. can you check my edit please ?

Comment: @johnG Move `csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SPMap>();` one line up in your code.

Comment: @johnG as suggested above, you need to register the map before writing the csv file, so move the register line up above the writing one and then it should work. I've not tried this, but if you follow the link I put in the answer it details it there.

Answer (score 1):

```
public byte[] WriteItem<T>(List<T> collection) where T : class
        {


            Type t = typeof(T);
            string newLine = Environment.NewLine;

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
            byte[] carriageReturnBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r");

            string text;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
                {
                    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pi.Name.ToString() + ",");
                    ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                ms.Write(carriageReturnBytes, 0, carriageReturnBytes.Length);

                foreach (T item in collection)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props)
                    {
                        string write =
                           Convert.ToString(item.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(item, null)).Replace(",", " ") + ',';

                        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(write);
                        ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }

                    byte[] writeNewLine = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
                    ms.Write(writeNewLine, 0, writeNewLine.Length);
                }

                ms.Position = 0;
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you check my edit to my original question please?

Comment: Have you tried above method ?By changing the order of your properties  you should be able to change csv order. Please let me know if you still face issues